# listeach and issue with the comma separated values

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am using the ListEach Function to comma separate the values from two different values.

like this:

```
<cfscript>
    result = [];
    listEach(form.getselection, function(value, index) {
        switch (value) {
            case "-2":
                result.append(listLast(ListGetAt(form.get_items, index), "~"));
                break;
            case "-1":
                result.append(ListGetAt(getselectiontext, index,',',true));
                break;
            default:
                result.append(value);
        }
    });
    </cfscript>
```

here is what the values look like

```
GETSELECTION    -2,105.0000,-1,-1,-2
GETSELECTIONTEXT    ,450,455
GET_ITEMS          128177000001304041~ mytext~YES~41.47,128177000001518319~mytext2~YES~91.52,128177000001518343~mytext3~YES~242.53,128177000001460287~mytext4~YES~15.0,128177000001304009~mytext5~YES~125.84
```

So, concatenating both, I want to get the values as:

```
41.47,105.0000,450,455,25.84
```

but somehow the values in the `getselectiontext` is causing me trouble, I am getting the following error:

*The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
Error Occurred While Processing Request
Invalid list index 3.*

**In function ListGetAt(list, index [, delimiters]), the value of index, 3, is not a valid as the first argument (this list has 2 elements). Valid indexes are in the range 1 through the number of elements in the list.**

```
The error occurred in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/myproject/secure/portal.cfm: line 56
54 :                break;
55 :            case "-1":
56 :                result.append(ListGetAt(getselectiontext, index,','));
57 :                break;
58 :            default:
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. `getselectiontext` has 3 items (including the empty). When you're on the 3rd and 4th iterations of the `getselection` values, you want the 2nd and 3rd values from `getselectiontext`? But otherwise it does sound like it's failing to pick up the 4th boolean parameter.

Comment: yes, seemsthing is incorrect and i do not understand what

Comment: i think i solved it, i was actually disabling the text field and no values was going, so i enabled it and use ` includeempty` to `yes` and it worked as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Your second list {getselectiontext} contains 2 items which are fever than 5 items in {getselection} on which you are iterating with ListEach.

in case "-1", you are trying to get a list item from {getselectiontext} at index 3 or index 4 which do not exist.

You need to review the data being submitted and how it's being submitted via form.

Comment: fixed as i said in my above comments, i was disabling a text field which i should be doing so